# PhpMyAdmin SQL code not showing up when creating new database and table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm  using WampServer with phpmyadmin, but have also tried Xamp and same results.

I have 6 entries in the table called employees:
I have a table called employee with entries:

> empId, lastName, firstName, department, position, and salary.

empId is primary key w/ auto increment. I'm following a tutorial online where they are using a mac computer, I'm on windows, in case that has something to do with the issue.

When I look at the SQL this produces it shows this:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE 1
```

I don't see any CreateTable or other SQL. 

Can anyone shed some light as to what is going on here?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
So if I go to > Export to SQL:

And this is what I get:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
empId int(11) NOT NULL,
  lastName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  firstName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  department int(2) NOT NULL,
  position varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  salary int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE employee
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (empI);
```

Which looks like the correct SQL.

So at least I know it is creating the correct SQL even though its not showing on the phpmyadmin web gui page.

Comment: Your question is why your `SELECT` query does not produce any results?

Comment: No, I created a new database and new table from scratch several times and everytime I do, I don't see the SQL code it creates as showing the CREATE TABLE code or any other code for the new database and table like it does in the tutorial I am watching. It just shows this SELECT * FROM ...  The code in the tutorial shows CREATE TABLE 'employees'.'employee' and then all the emId, lastName, etc... as int, varchar and value shows "not null, Like I said mine only shows that Select statement.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is simply showing you all entries in the table by querying it with "WHERE true". Click the "table" icon next to the table name, or the "structure" tab when inside a table to view the schema.

Comment: All I see is this: 1 empId int(11)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT Change Change Drop Drop 
Primary Primary
Unique Unique
Index Index
Spatial Spatial
Fulltext Fulltext
Distinct values Distinct values
....   I don't see any SQL Code. I am inside the Table. I see this inside the Employee table:    SELECT * FROM employee

Comment: It's really hard to follow you.. Do you want the sql code that creates the table? Something like `SHOW CREATE TABLE name of your table`?

Comment: So the tutorial I am watching. The person created a new database, and a new table with 6 fields as I showed. After they created the fields, it showed the SQL that went into to creating that database and Table. I don't see that so I just want to create a database/table and then see the code that goes into it. I am new to MySql but I would imagine a CREAT TABLE should be in there somewhere right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CREATE TABLE statement is just a command to create a table. You can also create a table using the GUI of PHPMyAdmin, in which case it performs the necessary actions for you.

But those are just commands, blue-prints if you like. In the database itself the 'Create table' statement doesn't exist. The database contains an actual table which was created using such a statement. When you export the database (like you did) or ask for the create table statement, it just reverse-engineers the actual table structure into a statement, like drawing a blue-print based on an actual object you have.

PHPMyAdmin will often show the statement that it generated to build -for instance- a table, but in some cases you may not see it. It might be that the guy of the tutorial has a slightly different version of PHPMyAdmin, or he activated a feature that shows the statement.